# Design Database to store lists

Tags: mysql, list, database-design

I apologize for the ambiguity of the column and table names.
My database has two tables A and B. Its a many to many relationship between these tables.

**Table A** has around 200 records

```
Table A structure
Id.   Definition
12    Def1
42    Def2 .... etc.
```

Table B has around 5 Billion records

```
Column 1 .   Associated Id(from table A)
eg . abc      12
     abc      21
     pqr      42
```

I am trying to optimize the way data is stored in table B, as it has a lot of redundant data. The structure am thinking of, is as follows

```
Column 1        Associated Ids
abc             12, 21
pqr             42
```

The "Associated Id" column can have updates when new rows are added to table A.

Is this a good structure to create in this scenario? If yes what should the column type be for the "Associated Id"? I am using mysql database.

Create table statements.

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creat_usr_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `creat_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modfd_usr_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modfd_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `A_ak1` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=277 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `B`(
  `col1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `creat_usr_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `creat_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`id`,`added_dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(added_dt))
(PARTITION Lessthan_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (1451606400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION L`Ω`essthan_201603 VALUES LESS THAN (1456790400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION Lessthan_201605 VALUES LESS THAN (1462060800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION Lessthan_201607 VALUES LESS THAN (1467331200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION Lessthan_201609 VALUES LESS THAN (1472688000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION Lessthan_201611 VALUES LESS THAN (1477958400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION Lessthan_201701 VALUES LESS THAN (1483228800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pfuture VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

Indexes.

```
  Table Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Index_type  Comment Index_comment
    B          0        PRIMARY         1             col1        A        
 2             NULL       NULL      BTREE       
    B          0        PRIMARY         2              id         A        
 6             NULL       NULL      BTREE       
    B          0         PRIMARY        3             added_dt    A        
 6             NULL       NULL      BTREE
```

Comment: *"Is this a good structure to create in this scenario?"* No. It's a bad structure for almost every possible scenario. Paste your table and index definitions (`create table...` and `create index...`) into your question.

Comment: Seconding the "no" on this one. It is almost never a good idea to cram multiple values into one field.

Comment: I have added the create table and the index. What would be better solution? Since i am having multiple records for each col1 value. I am trying to reduce this to one row per column value.

Comment: what are you trying to optimize for? Getting all the col1 values for a specific id?
What's the redundant part here? Are B columns always the same? If so - why are they in B?

Comment: @Uueerdo - I agree, but point out that there are rare cases where a commalist can be satisfactory and even faster.  If the OP will be `JOINing` to the other table, then a commalist is a really bad idea (as you say).

Comment: @Codegak - give us a feel for how many different `ids` you have for each `col1`.

Comment: @Codegak - You do not have a many:many relationship, only 1:many (1 A to many B).  It takes a 3rd table to do many:many.

Comment: @RickJames yeah, I am always tempted to say never; just hesitant to speak in such absolutes.

Comment: No foreign keys? Seriously?

Answer (score -1):

5 billion rows here.  Let me walk through things:

- `col1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,

How often is this column repeated?  That is, is is worth it to 'normalize it?

- `id` int(11) NOT NULL,

Cut the size of this column in half (4 bytes -> 2), since you have only 200 distinct ids:

```
a_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Range of values: 0..65535

- `added_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Please explain why this is part of the PK.  That is a rather odd thing to do.

- `creat_usr_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
- `creat_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Toss these as clutter, unless you can justify keeping track of 5 billion actions this way.

- PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`id`,`added_dt`)

I'll bet you will eventually get two rows in the same second.  A PK is 'unique'.  Perhaps you need only `(col`, a_id)`?  Else, you are allowing a col-a_id pair to be added multiple times.  Or maybe you want IODKU to add a new row versus update the timestamp?

- PARTITION...

This is useful if (and probably only if) you intend to remove 'old' rows.  Else please explain why you picked partitioning.

It is hard to review a schema without seeing the main `SELECTs`.  In the case of large tables, we should also review the `INSERTs`, `UPDATEs`, and `DELETEs`, since each of them could pose serious performance problems.

At 100 rows inserted per second, it will take more than a year to add 5B rows.  How fast will the rows be coming in?  This may be a significant performance issue, too.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you so much for all your answers and an so sorry for going MIA.

Comment: @Gabi Lee - The col1 has redundant data.  There might be about 5 miliion distinct rows. The DBA before me, created this table with one row for every Id col1 is linked to. So i end up with 5 million * 257 rows. There isn't many joins we do on these tables.

Comment: @Uueerdo this is the same thing a senior DBA in my organisation suggested too. But I find very few examples on the internet :(

Comment: @Codegak - Should be beneficial to normalize `col1`, replacing it with `INT UNSIGNED` or `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.